Extra_vars from rulebook appears undefined in the playbook triggered by run_job_template
The rulebook:
- name: Listen for events on a webhook
  hosts: all
  # Define our source for events
  sources:
    - ansible.eda.webhook:
        host: 0.0.0.0
        port: 5000
  # Define the conditions we are looking for
  rules:
    - name: Demo rule 
      condition: event.meta["headers"]["Os"] == "linux"
      action:
        run_job_template:
          name: Ansible-Windows-Template
          organization: default
          job_args:
            extra_vars:
              payload: "{{ event.payload.data }}"

The template playbook:
---
- name: Check Connectivity and Report on Windows Hosts
  hosts: G_WIN
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: 00 - Display payload from the rulebook
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "Payload from the rulebook: {{ payload }}"
      delegate_to: localhost

Error message:
{
  "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'payload' is undefined. 'payload' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/runner/project/win.yml': line 6, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n    - name: 00 - Display payload from the rulebook\n      ^ here\n",
  "_ansible_no_log": false
}

Reference document: variables
AAP Version: 2.5
Any help would be appreciated :-)

I would trying quoting: "00 - Display payload from the rulebook" to make sure that the "-" is not being interpreted as an operator.

Good point, I will quote it or remove the dash sign, but there is no syntax error, but just reporting the variable 'payload' is not defined.
I have a bunch of steps below the first step and they are all named as this pattern "0? - xxxx" without quotation marks and they were running well. the 1st step in question was inserted later, it shouldn't be an issue.

I changed the rulebook action from run_job_template to run_playbook and added a preceding print_event action to provide some debug of the payload as follows:
- name: Listen for events on a webhook
  hosts: all
  # Define our source for events
  sources:
    - ansible.eda.webhook:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        port: 5000
  # Define the conditions we are looking for
  rules:
    - name: Demo rule 
      condition: event.meta["headers"]["Os"] == "linux"
      actions:
        - print_event:
            pretty: true
        - run_playbook:
            name: Ansible-Windows-Template
            extra_vars:
              payload: "{{ event.payload.data }}"

I posted the following data to the webhook using curl:
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:5000' \
--header 'Content-type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"data": "something"}'

and saw the following output:
PLAY [Check Connectivity and Report on Windows Hosts] **************************

TASK [00 - Display payload from the rulebook] **********************************
ok: [127.0.0.1 -> localhost] => {
    "msg": "Payload from the rulebook: something"
}

which is what we are looking for.
I am wondering if the extra_vars payload variable is problematic when using run_job_template. It could be worthwhile renaming this to something else like info as follows:
actions:
  - print_event:
      pretty: true
  - run_job_template:
      name: Ansible-Windows-Template
      organization: default
      job_args:
        extra_vars:
          info: "{{ event.payload.data }}"

and update the template accordingly:
---
- name: Check Connectivity and Report on Windows Hosts
  hosts: G_WIN
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: 00 - Display payload from the rulebook
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "Payload from the rulebook: {{ info }}"
      delegate_to: localhost

